# Lauch gimp with 'Acquire screenshot dialog'

Tags: gimp

Is there a command-line switch to launch GIMP and open the 'Acquire screenshot' dialog directly, rather than going through the menu?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a command line screenshot you are interested in
[**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) has a very good [**import** command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) that can be used for screen capture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to open it directly in GIMP since then I can easily crop/adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

```
xwd >/tmp/snap ;  gimp /tmp/snap
```

This uses the xwd utility to let you grab an image of a window then opens it immediately in Gimp for editing, acting as if it has been snapped directly into Gimp. Read the man file for xwd for various options you can add to this line to alter its behavior to what you prefer.
If you don't have xwd (an ancient and pretty common screengrab utility) then use scrot or ImageMagick's "import" to grab the screenshot to a file, and open it in Gimp the same way.

You could make a small script with this line and invoke it with a hotkey (e.g. PrintScreen key) for ease of use. There are issues with using the PrintScreen key though. Read http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=754063#754063 for background info on why PrintScreen key doesn't work properly in many distros and how to very easily fix it.